# Is it Possible to Dismiss a Local Notification By Interval Time ? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I use this Code to Create a Notification With Interval time:

```
    let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
    localNotification.alertBody = Text
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Is it Possible to Dismiss this Notification By Interval Time ?

I know

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

But I Want to Do it With Interval Time.

Thank you.

Comment: for clarity, you would like for example reschedule it to next day?

Comment: No I just to fire this Once